# BitmapHunter Exception - Unrecognized type of request

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-studio, picasso

I am using a recycler view with horizontal scroll everything is working fine in code.I am retriving image url which i pass to picasso but I am unable to show the image in Image view. I am getting following error.

I have looked through the other answers but didn't found solution.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unrecognized type of request: Request{"https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/test-magictiger-uploads-thumbs/ccc33adf-0e01-4899-b4b1-868932913176.png”}
at com.squareup.picasso.BitmapHunter$2.load(BitmapHunter.java:66)
at com.squareup.picasso.BitmapHunter.hunt(BitmapHunter.java:206)
at com.squareup.picasso.BitmapHunter.run(BitmapHunter.java:159)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:423)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
at com.squareup.picasso.Utils$PicassoThread.run(Utils.java:411)
```

I have raised a new issue in github as well:https://github.com/square/picasso/issues/1364

```
private void loadImage(ImageView imageView, String url) {
        if (mContext != null && imageView == null) return;
        Picasso.Builder builder = new Picasso.Builder(UiUtil.getApp());
        builder.listener(new Picasso.Listener() {
            @Override
            public void onImageLoadFailed(Picasso p,Uri u,Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        Picasso pic = builder.build();
        pic.load(url.trim())
                .error(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher).into(imageView);
    }
```

Any Help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's weird, that is possible if [this line returns false](https://github.com/square/picasso/blob/master/picasso/src/main/java/com/squareup/picasso/NetworkRequestHandler.java#L43)...

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Exactly...I looked through the code you mentioned above.....also unable to resolve this issue using http either.

Comment: Try printing the URL in LOG and try to load it in browser.

Comment: @janki done that and found this error as well....when i hit the url in browser it downloads the image to my machine....unable to understand the issue here.

Comment: That means the problem is with URL. It is for **downloading** the image not **loading** it. Try to get the URL which is loading the image :).

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue for the above bug...I was parsing Json and was using get() method and was converting the value (corrsponding the image_url key) using tostring() had to use getAsString() method there.

Comment: Thank you, I just had this same problem

Answer (score 0):

Try this: pic.load(**new File(url)**):

```
private void loadImage(ImageView imageView, String url) {
        if (mContext != null && imageView == null) return;
        Picasso.Builder builder = new Picasso.Builder(UiUtil.getApp());
        builder.listener(new Picasso.Listener() {
            @Override
            public void onImageLoadFailed(Picasso p,Uri u,Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        Picasso pic = builder.build();
        pic.load(new File(url))
                .error(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher).into(imageView);
    }
```